# How to push player in two directions at once ( for Jumppad)?

Tags: unity-game-engine

i wanna build a Jumppad in my Unity Platformer game (2D).
I thought it will be easy if i just add a `Addforce`or `velocity` if my player collides with the jumppad, but there is a problem.

instead of flying in a 45° angle, my pleyer first gets pushed all the way in the direction of the X-Axis, and after in the direction of the Y-Axis.

the bool `sprungFlächeBerührt` gets true if the player collides with the Jumppad

```
if(SprungFläche.sprungFlächeBerührt)
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(10f, 10f);

    SprungFläche.sprungFlächeBerührt = false;
}
```

Comment: You probably only want to modify the y-coordinate: `rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 10f);`

Comment: i got an working Jumppad for going only upwards (like you discribed) but now i want one that is rotated, and pushes me not only up, but also to the right ( player files away in 45° angle)

Comment: completely independend of the question ... I would strongly suggest english variable names or atleast avoid Umlauts in code

Answer (score 1):

Quite strange. Might be a bug. Try this:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector3(10f, 10f, 0f);
```

Comment: It sadly does the exact same, like if i use a vector2. But thanks for the idea :D

Comment: shouldn't make any difference. `Vector3` is implicitely converted from and to `Vector2` ignoring the `z` component (setting it to `0`)